# Azure Unit testing with Input files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, azure-devops

Migrating a project from TFS to Azure, and everything is working great except a few unit tests. These unit tests require input files that we previously hosted on a shared drive. Before I go down the path of mocking the data in code, is there anyway we can save the files in Azure, and reference them from our tests?

Comment: Universal package feed?

Comment: Not familiar with them as of yet, but will explore that option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we ended up doing was creating a nuget package that contained our files, and put them on our own Azure feed.

Answer (score 0):

If it is workable you can try committing the input files into the unit test code repo. So that when the unit tests code is built through the pipeline, the input files will be accessible. They can be included in the build artifacts too, if the unit tests are to be executed on the release pipeline.

If you use self hosted agent to run the unit tests, you can just save the input files in a folder on the machine where the self-hosted agent is installed.

So that the input files are accessible to the unit tests that are executed on the self-hosted agent. see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) for steps to create self-hosted agent on Azure devops.